# arch linux - pacstrap automatically approve recommended resolution

Tags: arch-linux

I'm running `pacstrap` to install `pipewire` and any necessary packages

```
pacstrap -C /etc/pacman.conf -K /mnt/test pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-jack pipewire-pulse gst-plugin-pipewire libpulse wireplumber --noconfirm
```

that command results in the following message

```
pipewire-jack and jack2 are in conflict (jack). Remove jack2? [y/N]
```

The pacstrap command is part of a script and is interrupting the automatic steps. Is there a way to set a flag or otherwise automatically approve the `Remove jack2` question?

Comment: Use yes(1) as a last resort.